# Camera and Geolocation plugin issue with cordova android 6.3.0

Tags: camera, geolocation

I'm facing a issue after upgrading cordova android project to version 6.3.0 in using Camera and Geolocation plugin. These both plugin uses Permission helper class which requires cordova-plugin-compat. But with cordova android version 6.3.0 release cordova-plugin-compat is no longer supported (
https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/09/22/plugins-release.html) as it is included in the core. But I'm getting error on resolving org.apache.cordova.PermissionHelper and in org.apache.cordova.BuildHelper . How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update `cordova-plugin-compat` to v1.2, which contains [a restriction](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-compat/blob/master/plugin.xml#L30) preventing the plugin files being deployed to `cordova-android@6.3.0+`:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force 
&& cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2
```